# Density of time events

Tags: events, math, time, data-representation

I am working on an assignment where I am supposed to compute the density of an event. Let's say that a certain event happens 5 times within seconds, it would mean that it would have a higher density than if it were to happen 5 times within hours.

I have in my possession, the time at which the event happens.

I was first thinking about computing the elapsed time between each two successive events and then play with the average and mean of these values.

My problem is that I do not know how to accurately represent this notion of density through mathematics. Let's say that I have 5 events happening really close to each other, and then a long break, and then again 5 events happening really close to each other. I would like to be able to represent this as high density. How should I go about it?

In the last example, I understand that my mean won't be truly representative but that my standard deviation will show that. However, how could I have a single density value (let's say between 0 and 1) with which I could rank different events?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the [harmonic mean](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean), which represents the rate at which your events happen, by still giving you an averaged time value. It is defined by :

[image: harmonic mean definition]

I think its behaviour is close to what you expect as it measures what you want, but not between 0 and 1 and with inverse tendencies (small values mean dense, large values mean sparse). Let us go through a few of your examples :

1. ~5 events in an hour. Let us suppose for simplicity there is 10 minutes between each event. Then we have `H = 6 /(6 * 1/10) = 10`
2. ~5 events in 10 minutes, then nothing until the end of the hour (50 minutes). Let us suppose all short intervals are 2.5 minutes, then `H = 6 / (5/2.5 + 1/50) = 6 * 50 / 101 = 2.97`
3. ~5 events in 10 minutes, but this cycle restarts every half hour thus we have 20 minutes as the last interval instead of 50. Then we get `H = 6 / (5/2.5 + 1/20) = 6 * 20 / 41 = 2.92`

As you can see the effect of the longer and rarer values in a set is diminished by the fact that we use inverses, thus less weight to the "in between bursts" behaviour. Also you can compare behaviours with the same "burst density" but that do not happen at the same frequency, and you will get numbers that are close but whose ordering still reflects this difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This seems to be what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For density to make sense you need to define 2 things:

- the range where you look at it,
- and the unit of time

After that you can say for example, that from 12:00 to 12:10 the density of the event was an average of 10/minute.

What makes sense in your case obviously depends on what your input data is. If your measurement lasts for 1 hour and you have millions of entries then probably seconds or milliseconds are better choice for unit. If you measure for a week and have a few entries then day is a better unit.